# Как удалить строку с пустыми полями в ListView?

Tags: delphi

Удаление срабатывает визуально, но при сохранении и загрузке (ini) как будто удаления не было.

Удаление:

```
j:=0;
For i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1 do begin
if ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[j]='' then
ListView1.Items.Item[i].Delete;
end;
```

Сохранение:

```
var
  Ini: Tinifile;
  ListItem: TListItem;
  i: integer;
  n: String;
begin
Ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\file.ini');
for i:= 0 to ListView1.Items.Count  -1 do
  begin
    listitem := ListView1.Items[i];
    n := 'l' + IntToStr(i) + '.';
    Ini.WriteString('Section', n + '#',listitem.Caption);
    Ini.WriteString('Section', n + 'Столбик 2',listitem.SubItems.Strings[0]);
    Ini.WriteString('Section', n + 'Столбик 3',listitem.SubItems.Strings[1]);
    Ini.WriteString('Section', n + 'Столбик 4',listitem.SubItems.Strings[2]);
    Ini.WriteString('Section', n + 'Столбик 5',listitem.SubItems.Strings[3]);
    Ini.WriteString('Section', n + 'Столбик 6',listitem.SubItems.Strings[4]);

  end;
  Ini.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Все должно сохраняться.

Предполагаю что ListView вы заполнили в дизайнере и либо не делаете загрузку содержимого ListView из файла при старте программы, либо что-то в вашей загрузке работает не так.

Покажите как у вас происходит загрузка из файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И еще хорошо бы почистить INI-файл перед сохранением.
И удаление элементов нужно делать с конца, т.к. если у вас будет 3 элемента и 1-ый или 2-ой вы удалите, то на третьем у вас будет AV, потому что после первого удаления 3-ий станет 2-ым, а 3-его уже не будет.

```
for i := ListView1.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  {проверка длины строки работает быстрее чем сравнение строк}
  if Length(ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[j]) = 0 then
    ListView1.Items[i].Delete;
end;
```

Comment: Да, действительно. Очистка ini решила проблему. Премного благодарен!